# Removing connected servers from sidebar

Tags: finder, mojave, sidebar

The Macs that I admin all have Home Shares mapped (via AD - Force UNC path) and are appearing in the dock.

However I need to get rid of the root folder that appears in the sidebar of Finder once the home shares have been connected. *Edit* This needs to be for 1000+ users.

I have tried looking for the Sidebar Plist in ~/Library/Preferences, no luck.

I have also tried to use the Mysides utility, however it can only see the items in the "Favourites" section.

I am open to any/all soloutions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finder menu > Prefs or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>

Locations > Connected servers - uncheck.
Unchecking Bonjour computers will prevent them showing when not connected.

Comment: Hi, 

I need to do this on a system wide level. Your solution works on a user by user basis, however there are 1000+ users.

Thanks any way!

Comment: I hadn't realised you had so many to change. You might have to run a dif to find the defaults - see https://pawelgrzybek.com/change-macos-user-preferences-via-command-line/